# How do I dump dead bodies?

Tags: starfield

While I can lug the carcasses of the former occupants of my new ship anywhere within it (by holding E), apparently I can't lug them out the airlock, ideally to leave them in some boring backwater iceball where they won't be missed.

They are ex mercs. Pining for the fjords. They're only standing cause someone artistically leaned them against a wall to take up less room. I'd like to be rid of them

Is there any way to remove dead bodies from captured ships?

Answer (score 7):

If you replace or upgrade any part of the ship, the bodies disappear.  You also can't carry them *up* ladders so you probably should just stash them out of the way until you can replace a weapon or otherwise upgrade the ship.

Switching ships also does it, since it removes all the loose items and moves them to the hold , which is probably a cheaper way to do it.

I've not tested if simply moving things would help (if I recall I upgraded the shields in place) do the same, and will test it next set of corpses I collect.

Comment: "*Apparently if you replace or upgrade any part of the ship, the bodies disappear.*" Did you observe this or hear it from another source?

Comment: Observed it, I need to steal another ship to confirm it, but I'm still a bit terrible at space combat at this point of time. I was messing around and the bodies vanished

Comment: "replace a weapon" etc: if this is related to "items being placed into cargo when ship is upgraded" then I don't think you need to make any meaningful edits to trigger it, just edit ship and then exit.

Comment: I think this is the case