# How can I steal/takeover a spaceship without killing the crew?

Tags: starfield

For the first time I found a spaceship on a planet with an open entry hatch.

The crew is not hostile and I can walk to the cockpit. But I can not take the pilot seat, because I have to "secure" the space ship first. This means, I have to kill the civilian crew first?

My companion is strongly against killing civilian people and she tells me that she "really hate what I did" after I shoot the first person. But I don't want to upset her and risk our liason.

Is there any way to convince the crew to give up** or any other way to take over such a spaceship **without** killing the crew?

**None of the crew member talks with me

Comment: Probably in this case you'd have to kill the innocent people to steal the ship.  I have found hostile ships on planets though, where killing the occupants is acceptable since they are enemies.

Answer (score 5):

In order to commandeer another ship, its previous owners must no longer be able to pilot it. This basically means good ol' fashioned murder.

That said, there are ships piloted by more friendly or innocent folk that your companion may not be privy to you "relieving" these people of their duties. A quick solution to that is speak with your companion, and tell them to return to their post. They will leave, you can go about your business, and then simply have your companion join up with you again in your new ship!

Just remember to [dump the bodies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/404315/how-do-i-dump-dead-bodies)

Comment: That's a nice idea to let companions look away .-) I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Can you not use EM weapons to render the crew unconscious?

Comment: @Neon1024 - I tried to knock them out with the piston of a rifle, but that does not seems to be enough "secure" to sit down on the pilot seat. As I still see an entry in my activity list "leave the ship" and/or "kill the crew" I will try an EM weapon.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the only way you can take a ship without killing the crew, is to steal the ship from a friendly one that are not UC ships.

Occasionally on planets, you'll find a ship drop down and land on the surface. Many times, this will be pirates which you can attempt to kill and take their ships, other times, they're friendly crews that need resources (e.g., needs ship parts or water). There are also UC ships that land where the solo pilot is inside making repairs, but you can't interact with them beyond talking (or murdering).

When you find a friendly crew, you can go up to the ship and pick the locks to enter. Once inside, you could then take the captain's seat and claim it for your own. The previous owners will still be outside (and not hostile) and not even acknowledge their own request or even that it is their ship. It's all yours.